# Is there an equivalent of Excel's DATE() function in Access 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

Is there an equivalent of Excel's `DATE()` function in Access 2007?

Comment: Care to be a bit more specific, maybe? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 11):

```
Dim year As Integer
Dim month As Integer
Dim day As Integer
Dim date As Date

date = DateSerial(year, month, day)
```

See also [Date and Time Functions](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html).

Comment: Reversal badge, everybody!